# C++11 lock free collection similar to std::forward_list - follow-up 2

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, collections, lock-free

Thread safe and lock free collections are very hard to write, so I'd appreciate any feedback, especially regarding bugs. The code below is a self contained hpp, followed by some tests.

This question is a new iteration of this question:

[C++11 lock free collection similar to std::forward_list - follow-up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77840/c11-lock-free-collection-similar-to-stdforward-list-follow-up#77840)

- all methods are thread safe, baring the destructor
- `push`, `insert`, `emplace`, `pop`, `erase`, and iterator increment/dereference are O(1)
- locks that do occur are per-element spin locks
- `push`, `insert`, `emplace`, `clear`, and `separate` operations are lock free.
- `pop` and `erase` are not lock free.
- `begin`, `cbegin`, and incrementing iterators are not lock free
- dereferencing iterators is lock free
- uses reference counting to preserve iterators (and values) of removed elements
- iterators of removed elements will increment to end()
- `insert_after` or `emplace_after` on a removed iterator will return end() to indicate failure.

In addition to the creative commons license for code on this site, you may also use it under the MIT license.

## concurrent_forward_list.hpp

```
#ifndef CONCURRENT_FORWARD_LIST_HPP
#define CONCURRENT_FORWARD_LIST_HPP

#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

namespace details {
namespace concurrent_forward_list_details {

// provides a globally unique pointer used for the terminal node
constexpr struct {
} terminal_v;
constexpr void * terminal = (void*)&terminal_v;

// provides a globally unique pointer for the lock node
constexpr struct {
} spin_v;
constexpr void * spin = (void*)&spin_v;

}
}

// similar to std::forward_list, but thread safe and partiallt lock free
template <class T>
class concurrent_forward_list {

    class node;

public:
    template <class U>
    // construction is lock free (though begin() is not)
    // incrementing is NOT lock free
    class ForwardIterator {
        friend class concurrent_forward_list;
        node * current;
        typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef U value_type;
        typedef U & reference;
        typedef U * pointer;

    public:
        ForwardIterator() : current(terminal()) {
        }

        ForwardIterator(node * n) : current(n != terminal() ? increment_reference_count(n) : terminal()) {
        }

        ForwardIterator(ForwardIterator const & other) : current(other.current != terminal() ? increment_reference_count(other.current) : terminal()) {
        }

        ForwardIterator(ForwardIterator && other) noexcept : current(terminal()) { std::swap(current, other.current); }

        ~ForwardIterator() {
            if (current == terminal()) {
                return;
            }
            decrement_reference_count(current);
        }

        ForwardIterator& operator=(ForwardIterator const & other) {
            if (current != terminal()) {
                decrement_reference_count(current);
            }
            current = other.current != terminal() ? increment_reference_count(other.current) : terminal();
            return *this;
        }

        template<typename V>
        ForwardIterator& operator=(V const & other) {
            if (current != terminal()) {
                decrement_reference_count(current);
            }
            current = other.current != terminal() ? increment_reference_count(other.current) : terminal();
            return *this;
        }

        T & operator*() const { 
            if (current == terminal()) {
                throw std::logic_error("invalid iterator");
            }
            return current->value;
        }

        T * operator->() const {
            if (current == terminal()) {
                throw std::logic_error("invalid iterator");
            }
            return &current->value;
        }

        ForwardIterator& operator++() {
            assert(current != terminal()); // this is the end()
            node * temp = new_ownership(current->next);
            std::swap(current, temp);
            if (temp != terminal()) {
                decrement_reference_count(temp); // discard newly created ownership
            }
            return *this;
        }

        ForwardIterator operator++(int) {
            assert(current != terminal()); // this is the end()
            ForwardIterator temp = *this;
            ++*this;
            return temp;
        }

        friend void swap(ForwardIterator & a, ForwardIterator & b) noexcept {
            using std::swap; // bring in swap for built-in types
            swap(a.current, b.current);
        }

        operator ForwardIterator<const T>() const {
            return ForwardIterator<const T>(current);
        }

        template<typename V>
        bool operator==(V const & rhs) {
            return current == rhs.current;
        }

        template<typename V>
        bool operator!=(V const & rhs) {
            return !(*this == rhs);
        }
    };

    typedef T value_type;
    typedef value_type & reference;
    typedef const value_type & const_reference;
    typedef value_type * pointer;
    typedef value_type const * const_pointer;
    typedef ForwardIterator<T> iterator;
    typedef ForwardIterator<const T> const_iterator;

    concurrent_forward_list() : first(terminal()) {
    }

    concurrent_forward_list(concurrent_forward_list const & copy) : first(terminal()) {
        if (first == terminal()) {
            return;
        }
        std::atomic<node *> * nextPtr = &first;
        for (auto const & v : copy) {
            std::atomic<node *> & next = *nextPtr;
            node * newNode = new node(v);
            next.store(newNode);
            nextPtr = &newNode->next;
        }
    }

    concurrent_forward_list(concurrent_forward_list&& move) noexcept : first(terminal()) {
        exchange(move.first, first);
    }

    ~concurrent_forward_list() {
        clear();
    }

    // lock free
    bool empty() const {
        return first.load() == terminal();
    }

    // lock free
    // The first node is removed before locking the other nodes.
    // Push will not block.
    // An iterator incremented externally may move to a value no longer in the list
    int clear() {
        node * current = terminal();
        // detach the elements first so that blocking is minimal
        exchange(first, current);
        if (current == terminal()) {
            return 0;
        }
        // if we just delete the first node, it may cascade down all the
        // subsequent nodes. This would be fine, if not for the possibility
        // of blowing the stack. Instead we delete them in reverse.
        std::vector<node*> nodes;
        while (current != terminal()) {
            nodes.push_back(current);
            node * temp = terminal();
            // take ownership of the next node
            exchange(current->next, temp);
            current = temp;
        }
        for (auto i = nodes.rbegin(); i != nodes.rend(); ++i) {
            decrement_reference_count(*i);
        }
        return nodes.size(); // return number of deleted elements
    }

    // NOT lock free
    // All nodes are locked before removing the first element.
    // Incrementing an iterator will block, and then result in the end() iterator
    int locked_clear() {
        std::list<node*> nodes;
        {
            node * i = terminal();
            exchange(first, i);
            while (i) {
                nodes.push_back(i);
                node * temp = spin();
                exchange(i->next, temp); // lock all the nodes
                i = temp;
            }
        }
        for (auto const & i = nodes.begin(); i != nodes.end(); ++i) {
            decrement_reference_count(*i); // remove prior nodes reference
            i->next.store(terminal(), std::memory_order_relaxed); // unlink, relaxed because observers will see spin
        }
        return nodes.size(); // return number of deleted elements
    }

    // lock free
    T& front() {
        return *begin();
    }

    // lock free
    iterator push_front(const T & value) {
        auto * nodePtr = new node(value);
        return insert_node(first, nodePtr);
    }

    // lock free
    iterator push_front(T && value) {
        return insert_node(first, new node(std::move(value)));
    }

    // lock free
    template <class... U>
    iterator emplace_front(U&& ... params) {
        return insert_node(first, new node(std::forward<U>(params)...));
    }

    // NOT lock free
    bool pop_front(T * value) {
        return remove_node(first, value);
    }

    // NOT lock free
    iterator begin() {
        node * n = new_ownership(first); // wait for unlock
        iterator result(n);
        if (n != terminal()) {
            decrement_reference_count(n); // discard newly created ownership
        }
        return result;
    }

    // lock free
    iterator end() {
        return iterator();
    }

    // NOT lock free
    const_iterator begin() const {
        // const_cast is needed to lock first
        std::atomic<node *> & nonConstFirst = *const_cast<std::atomic<node *> *>(&first);
        node * n = new_ownership(nonConstFirst);
        if (n == terminal()) {
            return end();
        }
        const_iterator result(n);
        decrement_reference_count(n);
        return result;
    }

    // NOT lock free
    const_iterator cbegin() const {
        // add const using const_cast to invoke the const version of begin
        return const_cast<concurrent_forward_list const *>(this)->begin();
    }

    // lock free
    const_iterator end() const {
        return const_iterator();
    }

    const_iterator cend() const {
        return const_iterator();
    }

    // lock free
    // returns a default constructed iterator if position is no longer valid
    iterator insert_after(const_iterator position, T const & value) {
        return insert_node(position.current->next, new node(value));
    }

    // lock free
    iterator insert_after(const_iterator position, T && value) {
        return insert_node(position.current->next, new node(value));
    }

    // lock free
    iterator insert_after(const_iterator pos, int count, const T & value) {
        if (count <= 0) return iterator();
        iterator result = pos = insert_after(pos, value);
        for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
            pos = insert_after(pos, value);
        }
        return result;
    }

    // lock free
    template <class InputIt>
    iterator insert_after(const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last) {
        if (first == last) return iterator();
        iterator result = pos = insert_after(pos, *first);
        ++first;
        while (first != last) {
            pos = insert_after(pos, first);
            ++first;
        }
        return result;
    }

    // lock free
    iterator insert_after(const_iterator pos, std::initializer_list<T> ilist) {
        return insert_after(pos, ilist.begin(), ilist.end());
    }

    // lock free
    template <class... U>
    iterator emplace_after(const_iterator position, U &&... params) {
        return insert_node(position, new node(std::forward(params)...));
    }

    // lock free
    // all the elements after position are moved to a new concurrent_forward_list
    // IMPORTANT: existing iterators will still traverse the separated portion if already within the separated portion
    bool separate_after(const_iterator position, concurrent_forward_list<T> *& result) {
        node * n = seperate(position.current->next);
        if (!n) return false;
        result = new concurrent_forward_list<T>();
        result->first = n;
        return true;
    }

    // NOT lock free
    bool erase_after(const_iterator position, T * value) {
        return remove_node(position.current->next, value);
    }

    // NOT lock free on a, lock free on b
    friend void swap(concurrent_forward_list & a, concurrent_forward_list & b) noexcept {
        exchange(a.first, b.first);
    }

private:
    std::atomic<node*> first; // mutable because iterator construction requires a lock

    // lock free
    static iterator insert_node(std::atomic<node*> & atomic_ptr, node * n) {
        iterator result(n); // it's possible that the node is removed before we return, so do this early
        n->next.store(n);
        exchange(n->next, atomic_ptr);
        return result;
    }

    // lock free, removes all the nodes from *atomic_ptr forward, and returns that node with links still intact
    static node* seperate(std::atomic<node*> & atomic_ptr) {
        node * oldNext = terminal();
        exchange(atomic_ptr, oldNext);
        return oldNext;
    }

    // NOT lock free
    static bool remove_node(std::atomic<node*> & atomic_ptr, T * value) {
        node * x = owner_lock(atomic_ptr);
        if (x == terminal()) {
            if (atomic_ptr.load() == terminal()) return false;
            node * temp = terminal();
            owner_unlock(atomic_ptr, temp);
            return false;
        }
        *value = x->value;
        node * y = owner_lock(x->next);
        owner_unlock(atomic_ptr, y);
        x->next.store(terminal());
        decrement_reference_count(x);
        return true;
    }

    static node * terminal() { return (node*)::details::concurrent_forward_list_details::terminal; }
    static node * spin() { return (node*)::details::concurrent_forward_list_details::spin; }

    class node {
    public:
        friend class ForwardIterator<T>;
        T value;
        std::atomic<node*> next;
        std::atomic<int> referenceCount; // for keeping a node referenced by an iterator alive

        node(T const & value) : value(value), next(terminal()), referenceCount(1) {
        }

        node(T && value) : value(std::move(value)), next(terminal()), referenceCount(1) {
        }

        template <class... U>
        node(U&& ... params) : value(std::forward<U>(params)...), next(terminal()), referenceCount(1) {
        }

        ~node() {
            node * n = owner_lock(next); // change next to spin
            if (n != terminal()) {
                decrement_reference_count(n); // release ownership of next
                next.store(terminal(), std::memory_order_relaxed); // relaxed because observers will see spin
            }
        }
    };

    // lock free, increment node::referenceCount, used for iterator and for prior-node's link
    static void decrement_reference_count(node *& n) {
        assert(n != nullptr);
        if (n == terminal()) {
            int i = 0;
        }
        assert(n != terminal()); // not a valid node
        assert(n != spin()); // not a valid node
        if (n->referenceCount.fetch_sub(1) == 1) {
            delete n;
        }
        n = nullptr;
    }

    // lock free, used for iterators and for for prior-node's link
    // return a new "ownership"
    static node* increment_reference_count(node * n) {
        assert(n != nullptr); //must be a valid node because ownership is a precondition
        assert(n != terminal());
        assert(n != spin());
        n->referenceCount.fetch_add(1);
        return n;
    }

    // lock free, swap the node *s in left and right, 
    static void exchange(std::atomic<node*> & left, node * & right) {
        assert(right != nullptr);
        assert(right != spin()); // invalid node
        node * n = left.load();
        do {
            while (n == spin()) {
                n = left.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // relaxed because visibility of unlocked state may be at systems leisure
            }
        } while (!left.compare_exchange_weak(n, right));
        assert(n != nullptr);
        right = n;
    }

    // NOT lock free on left, lock free on right
    static void exchange(std::atomic<node*> & left, std::atomic<node*> & right) {
        node * temp = owner_lock(left);
        exchange(right, temp);
        if (temp != terminal()) {
            owner_unlock(left, temp);
        }
        else {
            left.store(terminal());
        }
    }

    // NOT lock free, set atomic_ptr to spin and return the node * leaving the node locked, unless atomic_ptr is already terminal then return terminal
    // "ownership" is transferred from atomic_ptr to the return value
    static node* owner_lock(std::atomic<node*> & atomic_ptr) {
        node * n = atomic_ptr.load();
        do {
            while (n == spin()) { // wait for owner_unlock
                n = atomic_ptr.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // relaxed because visibility of unlocked state may be at systems leisure
            }
        } while (!atomic_ptr.compare_exchange_weak(n, spin()));

        if (n == terminal()) { // the node has been deleted already
                               // put terminal back in to owner_unlock
            atomic_ptr.store(terminal(), std::memory_order_relaxed); // relaxed because observers will see spin
            return terminal();
        } // else stays locked
        return n;
    }

    // lock free, but requires a preceding call to lock, changes atomic_ptr from spin to n, sets n to nullptr
    // "ownership" is transfered from n to atomic_ptr
    static void owner_unlock(std::atomic<node*> & atomic_ptr, node * & n) {
        assert(n != nullptr);
        assert(n != spin());
        assert(atomic_ptr.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == spin()); // relaxed because it was set to spin by the current thread
        atomic_ptr.store(n, std::memory_order_relaxed); // relaxed because observers will see spin
        n = nullptr; // make sure the caller cant use the pointer anymore
    }

    // NOT lock free, 
    static node* new_ownership(std::atomic<node*> & atomic_ptr) {
        node * temp = owner_lock(atomic_ptr);
        if (temp == terminal()) {
            return terminal();
        }
        node * result = temp != terminal() ? increment_reference_count(temp) : terminal();
        owner_unlock(atomic_ptr, temp);
        return result;
    }

};

#endif // CONCURRENT_FORWARD_LIST_HPP
```

## Test Code

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER //for doing leak detection
#   define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#   include <stdlib.h>
#   include <crtdbg.h>
#   define DUMP _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()
#else
#   define DUMP
#endif 

#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <mutex>

class concurrent_forward_list_tests {
public:
    static void test_01() {
        {
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
        }
        DUMP;
    }

    static void test_02() {
        {
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
            a.push_front(2);
            int v = 0;
            assert(a.pop_front(&v));
            assert(v == 2);
            assert(a.empty());
        }
        DUMP;
    }

    static void test_03() {
        {
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
            a.push_front(2);
            a.push_front(5);
            int v = 0;
            assert(a.pop_front(&v));
            assert(v == 5);
            assert(a.pop_front(&v));
            assert(v == 2);
            assert(a.empty());
        }
        DUMP;
    }

    static void test_04() {
        {
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
            std::vector<std::thread> threads;
            int threadCount = 5;
            int perThreadElementCount = 1000;
            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
                threads.emplace_back([&]() {
                    for (int j = 0; j < perThreadElementCount; j++) {
                        a.push_front(j);
                    }
                });
            }
            for (auto &thread : threads) {
                thread.join();
            }
            int totalElementCount = perThreadElementCount * threadCount;
            for (int k = 0; k < totalElementCount; k++) {
                int v = 0;
                assert(a.pop_front(&v));
                std::cout << v << " ";
            }
            assert(a.empty());
        }
        DUMP;
    }

    static void test_05() {
        {
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
            std::vector<std::thread> threads;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                threads.emplace_back([&a]() {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
                        int y = rand();
                        a.push_front(y);
                        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(rand() % 10));
                        int x;
                        a.pop_front(&x);
                        if (x == y) {
                            std::cout << "y";
                        }
                        else {
                            std::cout << "n";
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            for (auto &thread : threads) {
                thread.join();
            }
            assert(a.empty());
        }
        DUMP;
    }

    static void test_06() {
        {
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
            std::vector<std::thread> threads;
            int threadCount = 5;
            int perThreadElementCount = 1000;
            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
                threads.emplace_back([&a, i, perThreadElementCount]() {
                    for (int j = 0; j < perThreadElementCount; j++) {
                        a.push_front(j + i * perThreadElementCount);
                    }
                });
            }
            for (auto &thread : threads) {
                thread.join();
            }
            std::set<int> remainingNumbers;
            int totalElementCount = perThreadElementCount * threadCount;
            for (int k = 0; k < totalElementCount; k++) {
                remainingNumbers.insert(k);
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < totalElementCount; k++) {
                int v;
                assert(a.pop_front(&v));
                std::cout << v << " ";
                assert(remainingNumbers.erase(v));
            }
            assert(remainingNumbers.empty());
            assert(a.empty());
        }
        DUMP;
    }

    static void test_07() {
        {
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
            std::vector<std::thread> threads;
            int threadCount = 5;
            int perThreadElementCount = 1000;
            int totalElementCount = perThreadElementCount * threadCount;
            std::mutex mutex;
            std::cout << "Initializing concurrent_forward_list_tests::test_07\n";
            std::set<int> remainingNumbers;
            for (int k = 0; k < totalElementCount; k++) {
                remainingNumbers.insert(k);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
                threads.emplace_back([&, i]() {
                    for (int j = 0; j < perThreadElementCount; j++) {
                        int y = j + i * perThreadElementCount;
                        a.push_front(y);
                        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(rand() % 50));
                        int x;
                        a.pop_front(&x);
                        {
                            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
                            assert(remainingNumbers.erase(x));
                        }
                        if (x == y) {
                            std::cout << "y";
                        }
                        else {
                            std::cout << "n";
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            for (auto &thread : threads) {
                thread.join();
            }
            assert(a.empty());
            assert(remainingNumbers.empty());
        }
        DUMP;
    }

    static void test_08() {
        {
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
            std::vector<std::thread> threads;
            int threadCount = 5;
            int perThreadElementCount = 1000;
            int totalElementCount = perThreadElementCount * threadCount;
            std::mutex mutex;
            std::set<int> remainingNumbers;
            std::cout << "Initializing concurrent_forward_list_tests::test_08\n";
            for (int k = 0; k < totalElementCount; k++) {
                remainingNumbers.insert(k);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
                threads.emplace_back([&, i]() {
                    for (int j = 0; j < perThreadElementCount; j++) {
                        int y = j + i * perThreadElementCount;
                        a.push_front(y);
                    }
                });
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
                threads.emplace_back([&, i]() {
                    for (int j = 0; j < perThreadElementCount; j++) {
                        int x;
                        a.pop_front(&x);
                        {
                            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
                            assert(remainingNumbers.erase(x));
                        }
                        std::cout << x << " ";
                    }
                });
            }
            for (auto &thread : threads) {
                thread.join();
            }
            assert(a.empty());
            assert(remainingNumbers.empty());
        }
        DUMP;
    }

    static void test_09() {
        {
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
            a.push_front(2);
            a.push_front(5);
            auto i = a.begin();
            assert(*i == 5);
            ++i;
            assert(*i == 2);
            ++i;
            assert(i == a.end());

        }
        DUMP;
    }

    static void test_10() {
        {
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
            a.push_front(2);
            auto i = a.begin();
            assert(*i == 2);
            a.push_front(5);
            ++i;
            assert(i == a.end());
        }
        DUMP;
    }

    static void test_11() {
        {
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
            a.push_front(2);
            auto i = a.begin();
            int v;
            a.pop_front(&v);
            a.push_front(5);
            auto j = a.begin();
            assert(*i == 2);
            assert(*j == 5);
            ++i;
            assert(i == a.end());
            ++j;
            assert(j == a.end());
        }
        DUMP;
    }

    static void test_12() {
        {
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
            a.push_front(2);
            a.push_front(5);
            a.insert_after(a.begin(), 3);
            auto i = a.begin();
            assert(*i == 5);
            ++i;
            assert(*i == 3);
            ++i;
            assert(*i == 2);
            ++i;
            assert(i == a.end());
        }
        DUMP;
    }

    static void test_13() {
        {
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
            a.push_front(2);
            a.push_front(3);
            a.push_front(5);
            auto i = a.begin();
            assert(*i == 5);
            ++i;
            int v;
            a.erase_after(a.begin(), &v);
            assert(v == 3);
            assert(*i == 3);
            ++i;
            assert(i == a.end());
            assert(*(++a.begin()) == 2);
        }
        DUMP;
    }

    static void test_14() {
        {
            std::cout << "\ntest_14\n";
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                a.push_front(i);
            }
        }
        DUMP;
    }

    static void test_15() {
        {
            concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
            std::vector<std::thread> threads1;
            std::vector<std::thread> threads2;
            int const threadCount = 5;
            int const perThreadOpCount = 100000;
            bool done = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
                threads1.emplace_back([&, i]() {
                    for (int j = 0; j < perThreadOpCount; j++) {
                        int op = rand() % (perThreadOpCount / 100);
                        if (op == 0) {
                            std::cout << "\n" << a.clear() << "\n";
                        }
                        else {
                            a.push_front(rand() % 20);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
                threads2.emplace_back([&, i]() {
                    auto iterator = a.begin();
                    while (!done) {
                        if (iterator != a.end()) {
                            std::cout << *iterator << " ";
                        }
                        if (iterator == a.end()) {
                            iterator = a.begin();
                        }
                        else {
                            ++iterator;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            for (auto &thread : threads1) {
                thread.join();
            }
            done = true;
            for (auto &thread : threads2) {
                thread.join();
            }
        }
        DUMP;
    }

    //static void test_() {
    //  {
    //      concurrent_forward_list<int> a;
    //  }
    //  DUMP;
    //}


    static void test_all() {
        for (int repeat = 0; repeat < 10; repeat++) {
            test_01();
            test_02();
            test_03();
            test_04();
            test_05();
            test_06();
            test_07();
            test_08();
            test_09();
            test_10();
            test_11();
            test_12();
            test_13();
            test_14();
            test_15();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// provides a globally unique pointer used for the terminal node
constexpr struct {} terminal_v;
constexpr void *terminal = (void*)&terminal_v;
```

I was initially skeptical that this would provide a unique address for `terminal_v`, on the grounds that `terminal_v` is an empty object of a very distinctive type; so I wondered whether it would be rolled into the same memory address as the following object, a la the Empty Base Optimization.

It was *not* rolled into the following object. This makes sense in retrospect; the Empty Base Optimization applies only to *bases*, and that's because the base object and the derived object are literally *the same object*; there's no "following object" going on in that case. However, this code is still broken.

Reason #1: Clang refuses to compile a `constexpr` variable with no initializer. You need a pair of empty braces `{}` after the word `terminal_v`.

Reason #2: This variable declaration is not `inline`, and therefore you get a separate copy of `terminal_v` in each translation unit. (Try it out!) In C++17 (and later), you can just mark the variable `inline constexpr` (or just `inline`; the `constexpr` here is unnecessary). In C++11, you'll have to use an `inline` function.

```
inline void *terminal() {
    static int x;
    return &x;
}
```

---

```
template <class U>
// construction is lock free (though begin() is not)
// incrementing is NOT lock free
class ForwardIterator {
```

Two style issues:

- Separating the `template <class U>` from the `class ...` is unnecessarily confusing, and might even break some really dumb tools (syntax highlighters, etc)... although I admit that we're probably in the age of libclang-based smart tools by now. Still, no comments in the middle of declarations, please!
- The CamelCase name `ForwardIterator` is guaranteed to confuse anyone coming from a Concepts Lite background. I strongly recommend `iterator`, or at most, `list_iterator`.

---

```
template<typename V>
bool operator==(V const & rhs) {
    return current == rhs.current;
}
```

This template seems massively underconstrained. Plus, I'm pretty sure it still won't work to compare `iterator` and `const_iterator`, because `const_iterator` is not a friend of `iterator` and therefore `iterator` won't have access to its private member `.current`. Maybe you just forgot to write `ForwardIterator<V>` instead of `V`?

---

```
// lock free, increment node::referenceCount, used for iterator and for prior-node's link
static void decrement_reference_count(node *& n) {
```

This comment seems incorrect. :)

---

Instead of `foo.fetch_sub(1)`, I would have written just `foo--`, as it's less likely to be misunderstood by the reader (e.g. by forgetting whether `fetch_sub` means `foo--` or `--foo`). I think the only reason to use the longer mnemonics is if you're attaching memory orders to them, and I'm pleased to see that you've removed a lot of the wrong-memory-order code from this new version.

---

```
while (n == spin()) { // wait for owner_unlock
    n = atomic_ptr.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // relaxed because visibility of unlocked state may be at systems leisure
}
```

I believe that this is an infinite loop on non-x86 targets. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063873/why-does-spinlock-with-stdmemory-order-relaxed-perform-correctly for the details. Keep removing those memory orders — you'll get to correct code some day!

This "relaxed spinlock" loop is duplicated in many places in your code. Perhaps it would be useful (even besides possibly fixing the memory-order bug) to pull out the repeated code into something like

```
node *spin_get(std::atomic<node*>& a) {
    while (true) {
        auto p = a.load();
        if (p != spin()) {
            return p;
        }
    }
}
```

---

`seperate` should be `separate`, or perhaps (I'm not sure I'm understanding it right) it should be called [`extract`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract).

---

```
// lock free, swap the node *s in left and right, 
static void exchange(std::atomic<node*> & left, node * & right) {
[...]

// NOT lock free on left, lock free on right
static void exchange(std::atomic<node*> & left, std::atomic<node*> & right) {
```

This strikes me as a recipe for disaster. Do you really need these two functions (one lock-free and one not) to have the same exact name? Also, if the latter is not lock-free, then it should not be taking `right` as a `std::atomic&`; it should be taking a plain old `node*&`. Which sounds a lot like the first function. So basically, kill off this second function.

---

```
template <class InputIt>
iterator insert_after(const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last) {
    if (first == last) return iterator();
    iterator result = pos = insert_after(pos, *first);
    ++first;
    while (first != last) {
        pos = insert_after(pos, first);
        ++first;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The first statement here smells to high heaven; and the mix of `*first` and `first` is dubious as well. I think what you want is

```
template <class InputIt>
iterator insert_after(const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last) {
    while (first != last) {
        pos = insert_after(pos, *first);
        ++first;
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Compare [`std::forward_list::insert_after`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/insert_after).

---

```
// const_cast is needed to lock first
std::atomic<node *> & nonConstFirst = *const_cast<std::atomic<node *> *>(&first);
```

What if you just made that member `mutable` instead?

---

I haven't even really dug into the lock-free parts of this code, except to point out that all your spinlocks are broken. I suspect that the lock-free parts have approximately the same density of bugs as the main code, which is to say, they don't work at all.

One way you could help people review this code — including help yourself review it! — would be to split the code clearly into "deep magic" and "boilerplate" parts. Right now, you've got deep-magic code like `.clear()` living right next to boilerplate code like `.front()`, deep-magic `.begin()` living right next to boilerplate `.cbegin()`, and so on. It's really hard to figure out what exactly is the "core" of primitive deep-magic operations that *needs* attention, and what is the higher-level boilerplate.

Of course another way to make the code more reviewable (and more correct) would be to *rip out* much of the boilerplate. For example, you have five different overloads of `insert_after` and one of `emplace_after`; I contend that for your purposes you only need `emplace_after`. That'd save you about 40 lines of code, and save you at least the one bug I pointed out in `insert_after` already.

---

Keep ripping out those memory orders! You'll get there! :)

Comment: Use inline functions for terminal and spin: ✓
Fix comment at ForwardIterator definition: ✓
Rename ForwardIterator to iterator_template: ✓
Properly constrain iterator operators: ✓
Fix decrement comment to increment: ✓
Use --foo instead of fetch_sub: ✓

Comment: Infinite loop on non-x86: Are there platforms where the updated value will never be seen by the waiting thread? As long as it happens eventually, it will continue.

Comment: seperate to separate: ✓
change exchange overloads to different names: ✓
fix range-based insert_after to return last iterator: ✓

Comment: mutable std::atomic<node *> first: I had originally done this, but I felt that it was better to have it be properly const, and make it clear in the exact location where bypassing this was needed.

Comment: Reorder magic vs mundane functions: todo

Comment: Great feedback again, btw!

Comment: IMO, `mutable` is kind of awkward, but `const_cast` is at least equally smelly and *also* technically invokes UB, whereas `mutable` is the awkward-but-legal version. (Consider an embedded platform where objects defined `const` want to go into read-only ROM if possible. The existence of `mutable` means the compiler has to do some non-trivial checking at compile time; but it will at least get the answer right and put the thing in RAM if needed. Without `mutable`, if you take that ROM address and `const_cast` it to non-const, you'll get a protection fault or worse.)

Comment: Infinite loop on non-x86: If you use seq_cst, you only have to worry about the OS thread scheduler; everything else is going to work. With relaxed, you also have to worry about the HW's cache coherency protocol (above my pay grade) and the compiler's optimizer hoisting the condition out of the loop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272730/does-the-c11-memory-model-allow-hoisting-relaxed-atomic-loads-out-of-loops — I can't find a compiler that does hoisting today, but my intuition is that hoisting is technically allowed, and that would break your code even if the HW protocol didn't.

Comment: @Brent Thanks for this great start at lock free linked list. FYI, I've taken this as a starting point and I believe improved it significantly. You are welcome to it for your own purposes.  <https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/blob/v2.1b12/Library/Sources/Stroika/Foundation/Containers/LockFreeDataStructures/forward_list.h>